# How to toggle inner content when hovered over parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add a script which will expand the "section # inner" UL when hovered over the parent LI.

For example, hovering over "Section 1" will toggle the "Section 1 INNER" LI/UL.
I would like to make it dynamic, because I might have the same for "Section 3" or "Section 2"

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34ng9sto/1/
JQuery:

```
    $(function () {
    $(".uSPInner").hide();
    if (!$(".uSPInner").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).closest("li").hide(); //hides the "LI" which gives the extra line... Not working.
        //alert("test");
    }
});
```

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li></li> //this will toggle the below LI because it has a nested UL
    <li> //hide this by default and toggle when hovered over the LI above it.
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li> //show this by default
    <li></li> //show this by default
</ul>
```

Comment: Where's the inner element in your HTML?

Comment: Should the nested UL go inside the same LI? If you look at the fiddle, it is the second `li` which has the nested UL that I would like to toggle.

Comment: Just saw that. Your markup itself is wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated my question with a better example.

Comment: Got it... This is not the right way to do. Use my logic. Nested UL is better.

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/34ng9sto/2/ (The inner will be hidden by default) When hovered over the parent, if the inner exists, toggle it.

Comment: Either put a `a` before the `ul` or ... The `a` and `ul` should be siblings. Period.

Comment: In you example, the inner UL is inside the A tag?

Comment: No... It is **sibling**, which means, it is **next** to `a`. You cannot contain a block level `ul` inside an inline `a`!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/34ng9sto/5/ (I got it, but how can I make it stay open if I hover over the inner UL?) Right now it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JavaScript this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".uSPInner").hide();
    if (!$(".uSPInner").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).closest("li").hide();
        //alert("test");
    }
    $(".clickMe").closest("li").hover(function () {
        $(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideUp();
    });
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34ng9sto/6/**

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You got your answer!

Comment: I missed the hover function. Thank you. Accepted and +1